# assigning a vlookup value to a variable

Tags: excel, vba

Instead of adding the result of a vlookup formula to a cell , I'm trying to assign only the  result to a variable but is not working.

The value is "September" and the result must be 9 but my vba code returns 0 in the Msgbox

```
 Sub Test()
Dim TableName2 As Integer

TableName2 = FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(R19C9,Database!R1C8:R12C9,2,FALSE)"

MsgBox (TableName2)

End Sub
```

I've tried to change the variable to string and the Msgbox displays "FALSE"

Can you help me and let me know what I'm doing wrong ? :(

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you? This site thrives on feedback. If any worked please mark as correct by clicking on the check mark by the answer. If they did not work please let us know what went wrong so we can better the answers.

Answer (score 2):

This is all sorts of wrong -- let me explain:

```
TableName2 = FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(R19C9,Database!R1C8:R12C9,2,FALSE)"
```

This is a boolean expression which says:

```
TableName2 = (FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(R19C9,Database!R1C8:R12C9,2,FALSE)")
```

`FormulaR1C1` is not a variable name so it will evaluate to a null string or empty numeric value, which when compared with the VLOOKUP formula string will return a `False` value for the right-side of this assignment statement, i.e.:

```
TableName2 = False
```

When `False` is cast to an integer value (`TableName2` is explicitly declared as an integer, so there is an implicit type-conversion which occurs), the result is `0` in your `MsgBox` statement.

Instead, try:

```
TableName2 = Application.Evaluate( _
             Application.ConvertFormula( _
             "=VLOOKUP(R1‌​9C9,Database!R1C8:R1‌​2C9,2,FALSE)", xlR1C1, xlA1))
```

This may still raise an error if the searched value doesn't exist in the Database range.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
Sub Test()
Dim TableName2 As Integer

On Error Resume Next
TableName2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ActiveSheet.Range("I19"), Worksheets("Database").Range("H1:I12"), 2, False)
On Error GoTo 0
If TableName2 = 0 Then
    MsgBox "The month is mistyped as a match was not found"
Else
    MsgBox (TableName2)
End If

End Sub
```